# Rank months graph ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm building a report in SSRS 2012 3.0. I show a graph of our yearly revenue, split up by months. Is there a way to get the months in a chronological order (so far left should be January and far right should be September) cause now I'm getting this:

[image: Months]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Category groups, right click your group / Category Groups Properties / Sorting tab. Use this expression in the sorting by textbox:

```
=Switch(
Fields!Month.Value = "January",1,
Fields!Month.Value = "February",2,
Fields!Month.Value = "March",3,
Fields!Month.Value = "April",4,
Fields!Month.Value = "May",5,
Fields!Month.Value = "June",6,
Fields!Month.Value = "July",7,
Fields!Month.Value = "August",8,
Fields!Month.Value = "September",9,
Fields!Month.Value = "October",10,
Fields!Month.Value = "November",11,
Fields!Month.Value = "December",12
)
```

Assuming you have a field called Month which you use in the Chart Category Group the above expression should work. In case you were calculating your Month field from a date you could use simply:

```
=MONTH(Fields!Date.Value)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The SortExpression.Value expression for the chart ‘Chart1’ contains an error: [BC30588] Omitted argument cannot match a ParamArray parameter.

This is the error I now get. Hmm...

Comment: @JorgenV, I had an unnecesary comma. Try again with the updated expression. If the error persists explain  your dataset fields.